# How can I speed up game or force all network to make better network speed?

Tags: gaming

Whenever I play game, I check the Task Manager and network session shows 0.4Mbps but when I'm watching something in Amazon Prime, network session shows 11.5Mbps.

Is it possible to change some configuration so when I play game, it can use maximum internet speed?
How is it possible that Amazon Prime shows 11Mbps while game shows 0.4Mbps?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible. You should analyze the difference between the traffic between your system and Amazon, and between your system and the game server.  You'll see they are very different, and understandably so.  Streaming video is quite simple, large packets (jumbo perhaps), the server knows what your next request will be.  With a game, the requests depend upon your actions, the actions of other players, the server may need time to answer your request.  The packets will probably be smaller, the server hasn't got a clue to what it will need to send you.  Try jumping forward and backward in your video, the speed will drop significantly.